# Can Angular universal be rendered completely on server side?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Can an entire Angular project (set up correctly without references to DOM and only using SSR compatible libraries) be rendered 100% from the server? I know some QOL improvements will be gone, but wondering if the site will work with JavaScript disabled. Basic functionality and visual integrity at least.

Comment: My answer would be no. Once rendered, Angular takes over on the client-side to handle routing and events. If JavaScript is disabled, it's not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

For sure: No. Because all things we see on the browser are: HTML + CSS + JS. While JS is the most important part so it can't work.

Comment: Technically, SSR would get you an initial render and serve the root route, but nothing else would work past that point.

Comment: HTML is the only necessary part of a web page. You can host a web page with no CSS or JS.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clear up the terminology used here, my interpretation of the question is "Can I serve web pages that don't require client side javascript".

Yes, of course. Just don't use any features that require client side javascript. You can just serve static html and css at different endpoints, and you can navigate with `<a>` tags to different endpoints.

You're just limited to what you can do with purely html and css, which is actually a lot nowadays.

From the Angular Universal docs https://angular.io/guide/universal:

> Angular Universal can generate a static version of your application that is easily searchable, linkable, and navigable without JavaScript.

Comment: That's not what's being asked. Angular Universal is server-side rendering. That's not the same as serving static pages or serving pages without JavaScript.

Comment: @BrandonTaylor if an application is rendered server side 100%, that implies there is no javascript being run client side (he also explicitly said it needs to run with javascript disabled). The only way to do that is to serve static html and css. Static from the client's point of view, obviously you can mess with them server side with whatever framework you choose.

Comment: @BrandonTaylor I might be misunderstanding, but I believe server side rendering is simply generating html server side, rather than sending html and a script, and having the script modifying the html client side.

Comment: SSR in the context of Angular is different. First, the root route is rendered on the server and returning the complete HTML and CSS, then after rendering, Angular takes over eventing and routing on the front end. So, without JS running in the client, an Angular app isn't going to do anything.

Comment: You're talking about using Angular on the front end AND Angular Universal, a hybrid strategy. Just don't use eventing and routing or any other features that require client side JS and you have 100% SSR. Seems like Universal supports this architecture by the quote I put on my answer.

Comment: No, that's not how Angular Universal works. Universal does an initial SSR and serves the index.html file. From there, control is handed over to the client side.

Comment: Well that's one way to use it, but seems like you can just host normal end points with a Universal Web Server. https://angular.io/guide/universal#universal-web-servers. I dunno I've never used it this is just from reading the docs, but seems like it'd be weird if you couldn't serve static files.

Comment: You can make requests to any route directly in the browser and Universal will return a complete HTML response, but if you use a routerLink in a component to go to another route, that's all client-side JS, and it's not going to return a complete response again. SSR only covers the *initial* response, unless you're making a new request directly to the URL in the browser.

Comment: Yeah, if you just use an `<a>` tag it'll make a new request to a new endpoint, it's basically just a classic 90's website.

Comment: Anchor tags are where you would bind a routerLink. You’d be better off using Next or another framework if you need to render a complete page on every request.

Comment: Well yeah, but the question was whether it could be done. The answer was yes, just don't use routerLink or other similar features.

Comment: There’s no point in doing that. 99.9% of Angular is client-side.

Comment: Can't argue there, I was just answering the question man.

Comment: I read back through the docs and I stand corrected. Router Links work without JS, but that’s it.